# How to remove remove key value from JSON using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net

I have a json response that I will need to edit before binding to a GridView. I'm using Newtonsoft JSON library. The data binds perfectly to the GridView when "values" are removed from the string. When values is added to the json response I get this error message.

```
Message=Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

How can I remove "values" from jsonResponse before binding to GridView?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJson" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3399ff"
        BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>

    var jsonResponse = "{\"values\":[{\"id\":\"201\",\"name\":\"Zack\"},{\"id\":\"158\",\"name\":\"Kim\"},{\"id\":\"254\",\"name\":\"Scott\"}]}";

    DataTable dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonResponse);

    gvJson.DataSource = dataTable;
    gvJson.DataBind();
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "201",
            "name": "Zack"
        },
        {
            "id": "158",
            "name": "Kim"
        },
        {
            "id": "254",
            "name": "Scott"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Depends what Json library you’re using. Can you specify that and edit your question to show the **unescaped** Json?

Comment: You can deserialize JSON to a collection of class objects and then bind that collection  to GridView. That would be simpler. You can use https://json2csharp.com/ to create classes from your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this..

You could use `JObject`

```
var dataTable = JObject
      .Parse(jsonResponse)["values"]
      .ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Or as been suggested, fully deserialize the Json to concrete classes and bind the array to control directly

**Given**

```
public class Value    
{
   public string id { get; set; } 
   public string name { get; set; } 
}

public class Root   
{
   public List<Value> values { get; set; } 
}
```

**Usage**

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonResponse);
// your Data , root.Data
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the `values` from JSON response, you should be able to do something like

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonObject["values"].ToString());

gvJson.DataSource = dataTable;
gvJson.DataBind();
```