# How to remove key from response which is getting appended?

Tags: json, .net, response, pcf

I need to remove `soAttribute` in this Json response:

```
"soidentifiers": {"soAttribute": [{"name": "DPID","value": "397400032488"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove remove key value from JSON using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820039/how-to-remove-remove-key-value-from-json-using-c-sharp)